# Unable to handle unregistered datatype - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

everyone!

I am developing a code with Qt and many of my components have a similar behavior regarding changing colors. Therefore, I have made a class called **ComponentState** which inherits from QObject.

```
class ComponentState : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor ui_state_color READ getStateColor WRITE setStateColor NOTIFY onStateColorChanged)
}
```

One of my components that inherits from this class is called **PneumaticLine**.

```
class PneumaticLine : public ComponentState
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
}
```

One of the views in my app (made in QML), has many of these PneumaticLine elements, so I decided to make a class called **Controller** to have a QList<PneumaticLine*> and export this using QQmlListProperty.

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<PneumaticLine> anti_ice_pneumatic_lines READ getAntiIcePneumaticLines)
...
    QQmlListProperty<PneumaticLine> getAntiIcePneumaticLines() {
        return QQmlListProperty<PneumaticLine> (this, &antiIcePneumaticLines);
    }
private:
    QList<PneumaticLine*> antiIcePneumaticLines;
}
```

Even though I declare the qml types in my main file, I still get the error:

> QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QQmlListProperty'<PneumaticLine'>' for property 'Controller::anti_ice_pneumatic_lines'

As a consequence of this error, I get the following in my qml file:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined

I would like to access the List<PneumaticLine*> in my qml files. How can I do that?

OBS: I have declared the types PneumaticLine, ComponentState and Controller:

```
qmlRegisterType<ComponentState>("ECS", 1, 0, "ComponentState");
qmlRegisterType<PneumaticLine>("ECS", 1, 0, "PneumaticLine");
qmlRegisterType<Controller>("ECS", 1, 0, "Controller");
Controller controller;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Controller", &controller);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I just got another concern: Please, care of the life-time of `Controller Controller;` The doc. of [QQmlContext::setContextProperty()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty) remarks that _QQmlContext does not take ownership of value._ Unfortunately, it doesn't state anything about the expected life-time of the `value`. In best case, the contents is copied and a temporary instance is appropriate. In worst case, it's expected that the instance is living as long as the context where it is registered. I would investigate this issue to prevent U.B.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks, I will take care of the possible issues. Any idea on how to solve the error mentioned above?

Comment: I've had issues with something similar when I forward declared class. It compiled after I included the class. Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the newly created type in the meta object system:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QQmlListProperty<PneumaticLine>)
```

Comment: The only thing this does is remove the warning. The QQmlListProperty properties are not accessible from QML, making it impossible to interact with it.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set function as `Q_INVOKABLE` for `Q_PROPERTY` can invoke that as:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QQmlListProperty<PneumaticLine> getAntiIcePneumaticLines();
```